# How to position bitmap using drawBitmap in android canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I want to position two bitmaps next to each other using `drawBitmap()` in Canvas, Android.

My `onDraw()` function.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    if (currentState == openedState) { 
            fruit1Bitmap = ApplicationServices.textureManager.bitmap[fruitId[0]];
            fruit2Bitmap = ApplicationServices.textureManager.bitmap[fruitId[1]];
            fruit3Bitmap = ApplicationServices.textureManager.bitmap[fruitId[2]];
            src.set(0, 0, fruit1Bitmap.getWidth(), fruit1Bitmap.getHeight());
            dst.set(0,0, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
            src1.set(0, 0, fruit2Bitmap.getWidth(), fruit2Bitmap.getHeight());
            dst1.set(fruit1Bitmap.getWidth() , 0, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);

            canvas.drawBitmap(fruit1Bitmap, src, dst, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(fruit2Bitmap, src1, dst1, null);
     } 
}
```

It is inside the class `public class Dhakkan extends ImageButton`.

Current Result
[image]

I want to get it to show two fruits next to each other. So how do I position them within the `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You calculated your second destination rectangle wrong

Instead of

```
dst1.set(fruit1Bitmap.getWidth() , 0, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
```

It should be something like:

```
dst1.set(fruit1Bitmap.getWidth(), 
    0, 
    fruit1Bitmap.getWidth() + fruit2Bitmap.getWidth(), 
    this.getHeight()/2);
```

Watch out for your right coordinate. This will draw the second fruit next to the first, possibly cropping it if it's too large. If you want to draw both fruits in the first half of the image button instead, then fix the coordinates of `dst`, the destination rectangle of the first fruit. You might also consider the method suggested by Kim.

Answer (score 0):

How about reading the docs:

```
drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)
```

*Draw the specified bitmap, with its top/left corner at (x,y), using the specified paint, transformed by the current matrix.*